# Which characters in a search query does Google ignore (versus treating them as spaces?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seo, slug

I want to give my pages human-readable slugs, but Rails' built-in `parameterize` method isn't SEO-optimized. For example, if I have a post called "Notorious B.I.G. is the best", `parameterize` will give me this path:

```
/posts/notorious-b-i-g-is-the-best
```

which is suboptimal since Google construes the query "Notorious B.I.G." as "Notorious BIG" instead of "Notorious B I G" (i.e., the dots are removed rather than treated as spaces)

Likewise, "Tom's fave pizza" is converted to `"tom-s-fave-pizza"`, when it should be `"toms-fave-pizza"` (since Google ignores apostrophe's as well)

To create a better `parameterize`, I need to know which characters Google removes from queries (so I can remove them from my URLs) and which characters Google treats as spaces (so I can convert them to dashes in my URLs).

Better still, does such a `parameterize` method exist?

(Besides [stringex](https://github.com/rsl/stringex), which I think tries to be too clever. 2 representative problem cases:

```
[Dev]> "Notorious B.I.G. is the best".to_url
=> "notorious-b-dot-i-g-is-the-best"
[Dev]> "No, Curren$y is the best".to_url
=> "no-curren$y-is-the-best"
```

Answer (score 2):

I would try using a gem that has been designed for generating slugs. They often make good design decisions and they have a way of updating the code for changing best practices. This document represents Google's [best practices on URL design](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=76329).

Here is a list of the best gems for [solving this problem](http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_permalinks___slugs.html). They are sorted by rank which is computed based on development activity and how many people "watch" changes to the gems source code.

The top one right now is [frendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) and it looks like it will generate good slugs for your use in SEO. Here is a link to the [features of the gem](http://norman.github.com/friendly_id/file.Guide.html#features). You can also configure it and it looks like it is perfect for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Google appears to have good results for both the "b-i-g" and "big" in the url slugs.

For the rails side of things, yes a parameterize method exists.

```
"Notorious B.I.G. is the best".parameterize
=> "notorious-b-i-g-is-the-best"
```

I think you can create the URLs yourself... something like

```
class Album
  before_create :set_permalink

  def set_permalink
    self.permalink = name.parameterize
  end

  def to_params
    "#{id}-#{permalink}"
  end
end
```

This will create a url structure of:

```
/albums/3453-notorious-b-i-g-is-the-best
```

You can remove the id section in to_params if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Use the title tag and description meta tag to tell google what the page is called: these carry more weight than the url.  So, leave your url as `/posts/notorious-b-i-g-is-the-best` but put "Notorious B.I.G. is the best" in  your title tag.